Fortran OMP parallelization strange behaviour when initializing variable and compiling with -g
I came across a very strange behaviour when parallelizing a larger code with OMP. It took me some hours to boil it down to this very simple MWE. When the subroutine testsub is called within an OMP DO loop, the result for x gets wrong when running on multiple cores and initializing the testsub variable with logical :: done=.false.. and compiling with -g. I basically do not need nor rely on the initialization, as the logical gets set to false inside the subroutine body anyways. But never would I have expected that when running in parallel, the logical done can become true before reaching the do loop.
program test
use omp_lib
implicit none
integer :: ii
real(8) :: x

call omp_set_num_threads(4)

!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(NONE),                                           &
!---------------------------- private ---------------------------------
!$OMP& FIRSTPRIVATE(x,ii)

!$OMP DO
do ii=1,8
    x = 444.d0
    call testsub(x)
    write(*,*) 'Should be 555.d0: ', x
enddo ! ii
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL

contains 

  subroutine testsub(x)
  implicit none
  real(8),intent(inout) :: x
  logical :: done=.false.
  ! logical :: done

  done = .false.

  write(*,*) 'Initial value: ', x

  do while (.not. done)
    x = 555.d0
    done = .true.
  enddo
endsubroutine testsub

endprogram test

Compiling this code with ifort -g test.f90 -o test -fopenmp results (for omp_set_num_threads>1) in an output like this:
 Initial value:    444.000000000000     
 Initial value:    444.000000000000     
 Initial value:    444.000000000000     
 Initial value:    444.000000000000     
 Should be 555.d0:    555.000000000000     
 Initial value:    444.000000000000     
 Should be 555.d0:    555.000000000000     
 Should be 555.d0:    444.000000000000     
 Should be 555.d0:    444.000000000000     
 Should be 555.d0:    444.000000000000     
 Initial value:    444.000000000000     
 Should be 555.d0:    555.000000000000     
 Initial value:    444.000000000000     
 Initial value:    444.000000000000     
 Should be 555.d0:    444.000000000000     
 Should be 555.d0:    444.000000000000

To me it seems like the logical done is overwritten by the parallel processes, but I can't figure out why.
For this MWE I found two ways to get rid of the false behaviour:

Compiling without the -g flag
Clearing the initialization, i.e. logical :: done instead of logical :: done=.false.

For my actual code only the latter method works. Though not necessary, I found initializing such variables upon declaration a good reminder for myself to what the default state should be and I don't see a reason why this shall be wrong when using OMP.
Any clues as to what is going on?

Explicit initialization is not threadsafe.

"initializing such variables upon declaration a good reminder for myself" - never use explicit initialization for anything except for explicit initialization, and then only when you know what that means.

This taught me a lesson, as I did not have in mind to run the code in parallel.

If you have gfortran + LLVM available, you can use ThreadSanitizer to detect such data race: gfortran -g -lomp -fopenmp -fsanitize=thread test.f90. Execution like OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ARCHER_OPTIONS=verbose=1 TSAN_OPTIONS='ignore_noninstrumented_modules=1' ./a.out should report Archer detected OpenMP application with TSan, supplying OpenMP synchronization semantics

You have fallen into the implied save trap.
logical done = .false. is actually equivalent to logical, save :: done = .false: the save attribute is implied.
A variable that has this attribute is static, which is means it has a reserved memory location during the entire execution, and a consequence is that the content of the variable is preserved from one call of the routine to another. But it also means that the variable is shared between all the threads if the routine is called within a parallel region: that's fine as long as the threads only read the variable, but this results in a race condition if they modify it.
In short, the save attribute is a multithreading killer.
In retrospect, the "implied save" behavior was clearly a design flaw introduced in Fortran 90, but now we have to live with it (although there has been proposals to mitigate it).
Also, if you do not use such initialization (and in this example you should definitely not), do NOT rely on any default "automatic initialization" by the compilers: some compilers do initialize the variables upon instantiation, but this is not required by the Fortran standard. Therefore, a code that relies on that is non-standard and not portable.

Why must a code which mixes explicit and default initialization be non-standard? There's nothing in the question which relates to default initialization, but default initialization fits perfectly within definition of a Fortran program, independently of any explicit initialization.

Unless you're using "default initialization" to mean something other than default initialization?

I was not aware of of static variables becoming shared between the threads. But wouldn't that also mean that module variables (which are save as well, right?) would be shared between all threads? And do you know why the above MWE works when not compiling with the "-g" flag? Coincidence?

@PrinceOfMe You're correct, the problem is the same with module variables, which are all static. Or with variable initialized with a DATA statement. Or with variables that appear in COMMON blocks... Regarding why "it works" without -g in your tests, it's probably pure chance (and I've tested your code here and even without -g it doesn't always give the "expected" result).

@PierU To clarify: any module variable gets shared when using omp? Wouldn't this render module variables useless when using parallelization? Seems like it is not a smart idea to define common variables and derived types in a module then. Or does it not apply to derived types?

It can be a problem, or not, depending on how the variable is used in the parallel region. You just have to be aware that it is shared between the threads. Regarding derived types I'm not sure what you are talking about: a derived type variable that is declared in the module is static as well, but a derived type variable declared in a routine (without save, not in a common block, etc...) is not static, even if the derived type has been defined in a module.

@PrinceOfMe look into !$omp threadprivate whereby you can mark a module variable as, err..., threadprivate. But basically best to avoid them, try to keep you subprograms pure whenever possible
